# How to turn a string of keys and values into a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby

I have a string which contains keys and values:

```
original = 'key1="value1" key2="value2"'
```

I have started by splitting on the spaces:

```
items = original.split
=> ['key1="value1"', 'key2="value2"']
```

But now I'm stuck trying to find a clean way to turn this into a hash. How can I easily turn this original string of keys and values into a hash of keys and values?

Comment: Are the keys to be `"key1"` and `"key2"`, or the values of variables `key1` and `key2`? Are the values to be `"value1"` and `"value2"` or `"\"value1\""` and `"\"value2\""`?

Comment: The values should be `value1` not `"value1"`

Comment: I edited my answer to handle the superfluous quotation marks. Basically you just add `.tr('"','')` to the original before everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume that the quotes around values are properly balanced and you'll never have an escaped quote in a value, it's pretty easy with a regexp:

```
Hash[*'key1="value1" key2="value2"'.scan(/(\b.*?)=(".*?")/).flatten]
# => {"key1"=>"\"value1\"", "key2"=>"\"value2\""}
```

Or in Ruby 2.2:

```
'key1="value1" key2="value2"'.scan(/(\b.*?)=(".*?")/).to_h
```

Otherwise, if you want to just split on the = and you'll never have a space in a value:

```
'key1="value1" key2="value2"'.split.map {|pair| pair.split "=", 2 }.to_h
```

If you might have spaces in values, then you're going to actually need to write a stateful parser.

Answer (score 2):

```
items_hash = original.tr('"','').split.collect {|i| i.split('=')}.to_h
```

Comment: ``.to_h`` is not an Array defined method for Ruby < 2.2.

Comment: @dgilperez I don't know whether you are dreaming. `to_h` is an Array method.

Comment: @dgilperez It is in Ruby 2.2+.

Comment: To all the readers of this thread that came later: The original comment by  dgilperez did not say what it says now.  It said " 
`.to_h` is not an Array defined method." Furthermore, dgilperez had somehow downvoted this answer, then retracted.

Comment: @sawa I change the comment to avoid confusion for others, but I revert that change just ahead. I just don't get your attitude: you reject my revision on the answer adding the note "On Ruby 2.2+ only:" which is just right, and probably downvote my working solution ... apart from unpolite, you're not being helpful to others. Maybe you can clarify that.

Comment: @sawa I didn't "somehow" downvoted, I **did** downvoted it as long as I thought it was just wrong. When I learned that it was a Ruby version issue, I removed my downvote because I changed my mind. How is that wrong in your opinion?

Comment: @dgilperez No need to mention Ruby 2.2+ only, which is the current version. If you are mentioning something about an older version, then that needs special note.

Comment: @sawa well, that's just a very questionable opinion. Ruby 2.2 was released less than 2 months ago and there are many of people out there not updated yet. I'm one of those. I think that the note is helpful and that is why I added it. I just think you're acting a bit too rude and still don't get why. I hope you reconsider your attitude.

Comment: This returns `{"key1"=>"\"value1\"", "key2"=>"\"value2\""} `.  The question is not clear as to whether the keys are to be strings, but I expect the values are to be `"value1"` and `"value2"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Hash[original.split.collect {|i| i.split('=')}]
```

First, `split` gives you an array of each `key="value"`:

```
> original.split
=> ["key1=\"value1\"", "key2=\"value2\""]
```

Then, `collect` + `split` turns each `key="value"` sub-array into an array of `[key,value]`:

```
> original.split.collect {|i| i.split('=')}
=> [["key1", "\"value1\""], ["key2", "\"value2\""]]
```

Lastly, pass to the Hash constructor:

```
> Hash[original.split.collect {|i| i.split('=')}]
=> {"key2"=>"\"value2\"", "key1"=>"\"value1\""}
```

Comment: It will work, but your `*` and `flatten` is redundant.

Comment: No... you get different results without `flatten`. Instead of the desired output, you get `{["key1", '"value1"'] => ["key2", '"value2"']}` -- that is, the first key/value as the new hash's key, and the next key/value as the new hash's value.

Comment: I did not intend each of them is redundant separately. I said they are redundant together.

Comment: Ahhh... yes, yes they are. Much obliged!

Comment: This is close, but it still needs to remove the double quotes around the value strings. The result should be `{"key1"=>"value1"}` not `{"key1"=>"\"value1\""}`

Answer (score 0):

How about this bit:

```
original.split.each_with_object({}) do |el, h| 
   parts = el.split("=")
   h[parts.first] = parts.last.gsub("\"", '') 
end

=> {
  "key1" => "value1",
  "key2" => "value2"
}
```

I suggest you have a look at the `Enumerable` module, and it's `each_with_object` used here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object

Comment: not sure why a down vote...I'll give you an up vote because it works!